# Getting `Expected 4 arguments, but got 1` when trying to use a vuex getter with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, quasar

I am trying to unit test a getter and I get the error `Expected 4 arguments, but got 1.` when trying to use said getter. I used quasar to build out the app and I am using typescript.

`HttpMocks.mockToken` is just a generic JWT string

```js
const getters: GetterTree<AuthenticationStateInterface, StateInterface> = {
  token(state: AuthenticationStateInterface) {
    return state.token;
  }
};

export default getters;
```

Here is how im trying to test the getter

```js
 describe('Getters', () => {
    it('Token', () => {
      const state = {
        token: HttpMocks.mockToken
      };
      const result = getters.token(state) // Expected 4 arguments, but got 1.
    });
  });
```

State

```js
export interface AuthenticationStateInterface {
  token: string;
  expires: string;
  error?: string;
}

const state: AuthenticationStateInterface = {
  token: '',
  expires: '',
  error: ''
};

export default state;
```

Comment: Does `HttpMocks.mockToken` have the same signature as `token(state: AuthenticationStateInterface)`?

Comment: @Anatoly `HttpMocks.mockToken` is just a JWT string. `token` on the sate accepts a string too. I have updated the answer with my state typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was just I wasn't following the getter's signature.

```js
export type Getter<S, R> = (state: S, getters: any, rootState: R, rootGetters: any) => any;
```

I just had to fill in the blanks, so I have this when calling the getter in a test

```js
const result = getters.token(authenticationState, {}, rootState, {});
```

`rootState` is just a mocked version of the entire state and `authenticationState` is a mock of the local module state